# How to fix Service Fabric Project Version Issues

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am working in a Visual Studio 2015 solution which is published on our Git servers as Service Fabric MSBuild version 1.4, but when I open the solution, it prompts me to upgrade the sfproj, and when I proceed to not upgrade it, it becomes unavailable in my solution explorer.

I have both versions 2.5 and 2.4 of Service Fabric SDK installed on my machine, which to my knowledge, correlate to MSBuilds 1.5 and 1.4.

How can I open this sfproj without upgrading it to version 1.5?

Thanks in advance,
C

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is the VS Tools for Service Fabric. It install the build targets for each version of SF.

We had a similar problem when some people installed a new version of SF but others was still working with old version, when they checked-in the code it broke others environment. We didn't find any option to switch versions, it always try to use the newest VS Tools.

When you upgrade, Visual Studio will update .sfproj file to a newer build version, in your case to 1.5, and also the nuget packages, you have the option to:

- Install the VS Tools for Service Fabric the version you need (1.4)
- Upgrade but not check-in these files (.sfproj and packages.config).
- Upgrade, once you finish your changes downgrade back to previous version (Change the .sfproj and packages.config, what we did during the first week until we upgraded our clusters, is just a few lines).
- Upgrade the cluster (The best option)

Comment: Thank you, sir! I appreciate the help.